# Somar dados do array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular, typescript

Tenho um array que os dados vêm do form preenchido do usuário e faço um map:

```
    dados.map(element=> {

  var x     
  var number1 = parseInt(element.preco),
      number2 = parseInt(element.peso)


      var tota = number1 * number2

      console.log(x += tota);             


  this.prod.push({
  produto: element.produto,
  peso: element.peso,
  preco: element.preco,
  total: element.preco * element.peso      
  })



})
```

E eu queria saber como somar o total de todos os `total` do `Array` que é o `preco * peso`, tentei fazer dessa forma `x+=tota` mas ele só ta somando os dois primeiros

Comment: Tenta declarar `var x` fora do `dados.map()`, e veja se funciona.

Comment: Como o amigo respondeu acima, declara uma variável fora do .map, exemplo `let allTotal`, e dentro do map após o `var tota = number1 * number2` você fazer um `this.allTotal = this.allTotal + tota`

Comment: Consegui resolver! obgg @rafaelmacedo

Comment: O preço é em inteiros? existe o `parseFloat()` também

Answer (score 2):

veja se essa solução te ajuda:

```js
    var dados = [{
        "produto": "arroz",
        "peso": "5",
        "preco": "15.90",
        "total": ""
    },
    {
        "produto": "feijão",
        "peso": "3",
        "preco": "5.90",
        "total": ""
    }];

    var new_dados = dados.map(item => {
        var r = parseInt(item.peso) * parseFloat(item.preco);
        item.total = r.toFixed(2);
        return item;
    });

    console.log(new_dados);

var total_geral = new_dados.reduce((prevVal, item) => { return prevVal + parseFloat(item.total) }, 0);

console.log('Total Geral: ',total_geral.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: eu preciso saber a soma de todos os totais

Comment: @Maria, você precisa que seja feita a multiplicação de preço pelo total e depois o total geral do array, é isso? Fiz a alteração na minha resposta mesmo. Caso seja sua solução, gentileza marcar como resposta correta. ;)

Answer (score 1):

O Javascript tem um função que resolve seu problema, ele vai somar todos os valores e te retornar o resultado final

```
const total = dados.reduce((a, b) => (a.preco * a.peso) + (b.preco * b.peso), 0);
```

Comment: o resultado ta saindo como NaN

Comment: Me mostra o input dos seus dados por favor

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a função reduce conforme código abaixo;

Documentação
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```js
  let dados = [
       {"peso":"1", "valor":"4"},
       {"peso":"2", "valor":"5"},
       {"peso":"3", "valor":"6"},
   ]
   produto = [] ;

   let total = dados.reduce((acumulado, corrente) =>{
        corrente.valor  =parseInt(corrente.valor);
        corrente.peso  =parseInt(corrente.peso);
        corrente.total = corrente.valor * corrente.peso;
        produto.push(corrente);

        return acumulado+corrente.total;
   
   },0);
   console.log(total);
   console.log(produto);
```